# Custom ribbon button action always disabled when command is defined

Tags: 2013, custom-actions

I want to add new button to the ribbon in Pages library. To do so, I have following code:

```
<CustomAction Id="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.Actions.UploadDocumentButton" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Links.Controls._children" >
          <Button Id="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.UploadDocumentButton1" Command="Test1"
                  Image16by16="/_layouts/15/Solution/Images/Al_16_by_16.jpg"
                  Image32by32="/_layouts/15/Solution/Images/Al_32_by_32.jpg"
                  LabelText="Upload File" TemplateAlias="o1" Sequence="100" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="Test1" CommandAction="javascript:function Action()
                          {
                            alert('hello');
                          } 
                          Action();"  EnabledScript="javascript:function JustReturnTrue(){  return true;}JustReturnTrue();" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

The ribbon button appears on proper place. But it is always disabled. After try things, I figured out that when I remove `command` attribute from `<Button>` tag it is getting enabled but when I place the same attribute and deploy, it is getting disabled.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think this because of missing semicolon in after `return true` statement in `JustReturnTrue()` method.

Comment: Hello Sir, I added the semicolon(;) after `return true` (as per my updated question) but getting the same issue. @NadeemYousuf

Comment: please try to use developer tools (using f12 regardless of your browser) and check for any javascript errors. Code seems legit.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am having a similar problem where the button is always disabled.  However, I want it always enabled, so I am not using `EnabledScript` at all.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is enabled in all conditions, try to remove the `EnabledScript` property.

Comment: Removed the attribute for enabling the option but not working yet.

Comment: Try this :

`<CommandUIHandler Command="Test1" CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello, world');"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Problem and discovered that removing the space before the commandUIHandler closing tag helped.

So instead of

```
return true;}JustReturnTrue();" />
```

do this:

```
return true;}JustReturnTrue();"/>
```